# configure local_auth plugin in flutter

Tags: java, kotlin, flutter, dart

My project , uses kotlin and when I want to use Local_auth plugin , I get the error below:

```
PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null)
```

what the example of local_auth says , is:

```
package io.flutter.plugins.localauthexample;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.localauth.LocalAuthPlugin;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
  // TODO(bparrishMines): Remove this once v2 of GeneratedPluginRegistrant rolls to stable. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42694
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new LocalAuthPlugin());
  }
}
```

and

```
package io.flutter.plugins.localauthexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class EmbeddingV1Activity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

but the problem is that I don't know kotlin and I don't know how to create my kotlin file.

also , I guess (I am not sure) that , it can be a bug of flutter in its new release.

Comment: Refer to this comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33429#issuecomment-496598997

Answer (score 10):

Change the *MainActivity.kt* file's code to this

```kotlin
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting build error "'configureFlutterEngine' overrides nothing"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

Comment: I am unable to find Gradle log file location. So, can't attach here.

Comment: @Plasmatiger have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @KamranBashir sorry for the late response. I was able to solve it but I don't remember at the moment.

Comment: Same thing happens for me with java code, is there any help with Java?

Answer (score 7):

Open `MainActivity.kt` and change as below.

```
package com.[your.package]

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

For more information, check out:

https://gist.github.com/akifarhan/f70a2c777651f2ea61a15eb92a5939c1

Answer (score 2):

I fixed mine by changing `FlutterActivity` to `FlutterFragmentActivity`
in:

```
/android/app/src/main/kotlin/../MainActivity.kt
```

Comment: I am getting build error "'configureFlutterEngine' overrides nothing"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

I am unable to find Gradle log file location. So, can't attach here.

Answer (score 0):

Open `MainActivity.kt` and replace all `FlutterActivity` by `FlutterFragmentActivity`.

Refer: [Android Integration](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth#android-integration)