# PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null) in flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, localauthentication

I am trying add Figureprint authentication using [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth/versions/0.6.2+3#-readme-tab-) package of flutter i used same example given that package [here it is](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth/versions/0.6.2+3#-example-tab-).
And i am getting this error

```
I/flutter (27676): PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null)
```

I have try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60138859/9128055) But the problem is that I don't know about ***kotlin***.

Here is my **Mainactivity.kt**

```
package com.example.bio_met

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found the answer and it worked for me. Here it is just replace your code with following code in **MainActivity.kt** file.

```
package //your package name for eg.com.example.filename

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine){
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code works if I run on Emulator but if I build APK for my Android the Application crash at starting

Comment: @TiziDev can show me logs while it's crashing. you see the logs in the android studio logcat tab on the bottom while running the app connect your phone to the system to see logs.

Comment: Below I have posted the Log from Note Pro 9 Xiamei, the application crash after installing APK

Answer (score -1):

````
 at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(Unknown Source:90)
 at it.wytex.vibeland_client.MainActivity.l(Unknown Source:5)
 at io.flutter.embedding.android.i.l(Unknown Source:10)
 at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.k(Unknown Source:58)
 at io.flutter.embedding.android.i.x0(Unknown Source:10)
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.c1(Unknown Source:21)
 at androidx.fragment.app.j.R0(Unknown Source:433)
 at androidx.fragment.app.o.b(Unknown Source:206)
 at androidx.fragment.app.o.c(Unknown Source:18)
 at androidx.fragment.app.o.C(Unknown Source:36)
 at androidx.fragment.app.j.n0(Unknown Source:110)
 at androidx.fragment.app.j.Z0(Unknown Source:88)
 at androidx.fragment.app.j.l0(Unknown Source:21)
 at androidx.fragment.app.j.e0(Unknown Source:9)
 at androidx.fragment.app.j.y(Unknown Source:6)
 at androidx.fragment.app.f.c(Unknown Source:4)
 at androidx.fragment.app.d.onStart(Unknown Source:15)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7923)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)```
````

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what is happing but you can open an issue on the GitHub repo of "Flutter" there you will get help or search on issues selection there for same error if anyone already solved.